# Making a speedial without FloatingActionButton

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

im trying to make my button open up something similar to this: [FAB version of what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y092i.png)

This is what my code looks like:

```
   return Card(
     color: Colors.yellow[100],
     child: ListTile(
       trailing: IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.more_vert),
         onPressed: () {},
       ),

       leading:  Text(document['date'] + '\n' + document['time'], textAlign: TextAlign.center,),

       subtitle: Text(
         'Loctaion: ' + document['location'],
       ),
       title: Text(document['name'],
           textAlign: TextAlign.left, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0)),
     ),
   );
 }
```

I want the IconButton to open up something similar to the SpeedDial, to make the user choose between accept, deny, or choose later for the event.

[My ListTile with the Icon.more_vert that i want to be able to open a speeddial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsOVs.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_portal 
Basically use `Overlay` and show circle button 
You can change `childAnchor` and `menuAnchor`, and circle button size per your request 
It's too long to describe all the detail, please see working demo and full code below 
code snippet

```
ListTile(
            trailing: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.more_vert),
              onPressed: () => setState(() => showMenu = true),
            ),
...         
return ModalEntry(
      visible: showMenu,
      onClose: () => setState(() => showMenu = false),
      childAnchor: Alignment.topRight,
      menuAnchor: Alignment.bottomRight,
      menu: Menu(
        children: [
          ClipOval(
            child: Material(
              color: Colors.blue, // button color
              child: InkWell(
                splashColor: Colors.red, // inkwell color
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() => showMenu = false);
                },
                child: SizedBox(width: 40, height: 40, child: Icon(Icons.menu)),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_portal/flutter_portal.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      builder: (_, child) => Portal(child: child),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Example'),
        ),
        body: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          child: ContextualMenuExample(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ContextualMenuExample extends StatefulWidget {
  ContextualMenuExample({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ContextualMenuExampleState createState() => _ContextualMenuExampleState();
}

class _ContextualMenuExampleState extends State<ContextualMenuExample> {
  bool showMenu = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ModalEntry(
      visible: showMenu,
      onClose: () => setState(() => showMenu = false),
      childAnchor: Alignment.topRight,
      menuAnchor: Alignment.bottomRight,
      menu: Menu(
        children: [
          ClipOval(
            child: Material(
              color: Colors.blue, // button color
              child: InkWell(
                splashColor: Colors.red, // inkwell color
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() => showMenu = false);
                },
                child: SizedBox(width: 40, height: 40, child: Icon(Icons.menu)),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          ClipOval(
            child: Material(
              color: Colors.blue, // button color
              child: InkWell(
                splashColor: Colors.red, // inkwell color
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() => showMenu = false);
                },
                child: SizedBox(
                    width: 40, height: 40, child: Icon(Icons.description)),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          ClipOval(
            child: Material(
              color: Colors.blue, // button color
              child: InkWell(
                splashColor: Colors.red, // inkwell color
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() => showMenu = false);
                },
                child: SizedBox(
                    width: 40, height: 40, child: Icon(Icons.settings)),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
      child: Container(
        child: Card(
          color: Colors.yellow[100],
          child: ListTile(
            trailing: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.more_vert),
              onPressed: () => setState(() => showMenu = true),
            ),
            leading: Text(
              "date time",
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
            subtitle: Text(
              'Loctaion',
            ),
            title: Text('name',
                textAlign: TextAlign.left, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0)),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Menu extends StatelessWidget {
  const Menu({
    Key key,
    @required this.children,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final List<Widget> children;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
      child: Card(
        elevation: 8,
        child: IntrinsicWidth(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: children,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ModalEntry extends StatelessWidget {
  const ModalEntry({
    Key key,
    this.onClose,
    this.menu,
    this.visible,
    this.menuAnchor,
    this.childAnchor,
    this.child,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final VoidCallback onClose;
  final Widget menu;
  final bool visible;
  final Widget child;
  final Alignment menuAnchor;
  final Alignment childAnchor;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
      onTap: visible ? onClose : null,
      child: PortalEntry(
        visible: visible,
        portal: menu,
        portalAnchor: menuAnchor,
        childAnchor: childAnchor,
        child: IgnorePointer(
          ignoring: visible,
          child: child,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```